# How to get data of YAML file in the Angular 7 array of objects

Tags: json, angular, typescript, yaml

I know how to get a **JSON** file and to show it in the array in Angular 7 but I am having a problem with the **YAML** file I have searched and I really do not know how to get in the array the **YAML**

For the moment I have tried this but it is coming with errors.

`Service`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class getYamlDataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getJson().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  public getJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/swagger/swagger.yaml");
  }
}
```

`Component.ts`

```
constructor(private getYamlData: getYamlDataService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.getYamlData.getJson().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

`Error`

**Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/assets/swagger/swagger.yaml**

But when I open this localhost then it is showing in browser yaml file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to your response being parsed as a JSON Object instead of returning a plain string. If you look at the API of `HttpClient.get(string)` without an options parameter, you will see that the response is observed as a json [(found here, 15th overload)](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)

```
get<T>(url: string, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<T>
```

You have to specify the return type you want (in this case most likely "text")

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class getYamlDataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getJson().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  public getJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/swagger/swagger.yaml", {
      observe: 'body',
      responseType: "text";   // This one here tells HttpClient to parse it as text, not as JSON
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to use that yaml as a JavaScript Object, you will have to parse it yourself. Luckily, there are already libararies like [yaml.js](https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js) that you can leverage for this. First, install the libarary `npm i --save yamljs` and then use it like this:

```
import {parse} from 'yamljs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class getYamlDataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getJson().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }


  public getJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/swagger/swagger.yaml", {
      observe: 'body',
      responseType: "text"   // This one here tells HttpClient to parse it as text, not as JSON
    }).pipe(
      // Map Yaml to JavaScript Object
      map(yamlString => parse(yamlString))
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a working [StackBlitz](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfc4hm) showcasing this.

*Edit:* Added example for parsing the returned string to a JavaScript Object

*Edit2:* Added StackBlitz example

Comment: How can I show this data then in array with `*ngFor` ?

Comment: HttpClient can natively only return it as a string - you have to parse that one to a JavaScript/TypeScript Object yourself. Luckily, there are already libararies that can do that for you like this one: https://github.com/jeremyfa/yaml.js

Comment: @ZhuniqiA I added an example to my answer to showcase the parsing to a JavaScript Object.

Comment: it is coming with an error that unreachable code it is from .pipe ?

Comment: I am having problems with `/node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in`

Comment: Whoops, there was an extra semicolon which slipped in (after responseType: "text"). Remove that.

Comment: I am facing with this problem now `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in `

Comment: Not sure what is causing that, but seems to be a problem with the library. You could try importing it in a different way. Haven't used it yet, they claim it works in browsers but maybe they only have a prebuild version for that instead of modules so importing it as a module does not work. You could try https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml instead. They work pretty similiar.

Comment: @ZhuniqiA The library seems to work - here is working StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfc4hm

Comment: Yeah I have seen there but at me it is coming with `Cannot find module fs`

Comment: Seems like you used the 'fs' library then, which is node specific. Can you somehow provide a minimal reproductive StackBlitz so I can try to help you on finding the error? With just the error message this is a bit difficult...